# Why does Petalinux run the mountnfs script during initialization?

Tags: linux, nfs, init

I was inspecting the root filesystem files generated by PetaLinux and saw a couple of start-up scripts under `/etc/rc5.d` folder. One of them was named `S15mountnfs.sh` and linked to `mountnfs.sh` script which is placed under `/etc/init.d`

From what I understand by its content and name, I guess that it is only responsible for mounting the NFS root filesystem. As this is a script located in an already mounted filesystem, why do we need to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disks are mounted in a specific order during unix boot.

Typically, linux loads an initial root filesystem as a ram drive, and this has scripts to find the real root filesystem, mount it, and switch to it, and release the memory from the initrd.

Then the system will proceed to mount all the physical disks in fstab.

Then the system brings up the network and configures it.

Once that is done, it would mount nfs drives from other servers.

nfs is rarely used as a root filesystem, but it is possible.  However, typically the mountnfs script would be mounting things other than root, like maybe /home if that is nfs shared.

If the root filesystem is via NFS, the initrd scripts would need to bring up the network early and mount it separately from inside the initrd.

Comment: I couldn't think that there could be multiple filesystems mounted over NFS. Thanks for the answer